# Replace a string with a part of itself

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, regular-expression

I am cleaning up my data that is stored in text files. Each line starts with a category label followed by the actual data that I want to clean up. There are many text files in different subfolders, so I use `egrep` to pass the filenames on to `sed`.

```
CON: the Unix and Linux question
SEM: eins, the zwei, drei
AUTH: , the
AFF: The holy seat
TTITLE: As we go, the Kuckuck comes too
```

Now in every line starting with `(SEM|AFF|CON)` I want to replace `(T|t)he[ ]*` when it follows `(:|\,)`. That is, the data should later look like

```
CON: Unix and Linux question
SEM: eins, zwei, drei
AUTH: , the
AFF: holy seat
TTITLE: As we go, the Kuckuck comes too
```

So far I tried to achieve this in two steps, one for the `:`-part and the other for the `,`-part. But I struggle already with the first step.

**First part**
The command/pattern to identify the files is `egrep -rl ^"(SEM|CON|AFF)\: (t|T)he"`. This works as intended.

Now when I do

```
egrep -rl ^"(SEM|CON|AFF)\: (t|T)he" | xargs sed -i 's/\((SEM|CON|AFF)\: \)(t|T)he[ ]*/\1/g'
```

nothing happens. Is my `sed` part wrong? Can't I backrefer to `((SEM|CON|AFF)\:` with `\1`?

**Second part**
The command/pattern to identify the files is `egrep -rl ^"(SEM|CON|AFF)\:.*\,[ ]*(t|T)he"`. This also works as intended. But every combination on `sed` that I tried so far deletes the content.

Comment: Unless you escape the `(` in a Basic RE, it will be seen as a literal `(`. Try `\(\(SEM|CON|AFF\): \)\(t|T\)`. Or use extended REs (`sed -r`), and replace all `\(` with just `(`. Since you used `egrep`, you're getting extended REs for free.

Comment: You mean, I don't need `-e` when I use `egrep`?

Comment: `egrep` is like `grep -E`. `-e` is used to denote an expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the following:

```
sed -r '/(SEM|AFF|CON)/ s/([:,] *)[Tt]he */\1/g' file
```

Add `-i` option to change file in place.

Answer (score 3):

Just use one sed expression (needs GNU sed):

```
sed -r -i -e '/(SEM|AFF|CON)/s/([:,]\s*)the\s+/\1/ig' *
```

The search pattern at the begin of the sed command restricts the replacement to the lines which begins with the selected categories. The `i` flag for the replace command (`s//`) makes the pattern case-insensitive; the `g` flag allows more than one replacement in a line. `\s` stands for any whitespace (space, tabs).

The `sed` uses extended regular expressions with the `-r` flag; this is for example supported by GNU sed. The `-i` flag enables in-place edit. The shell expands `*` to all files in the current directory.

The pattern ensures at least one space or tab after `the` so that words starting with `the` like `theater` are not replaced.

Comment: Perhaps use `\b\s*` rather than `\s+`, so that it matches at end of line, too?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
egrep -rl "^(SEM|CON|AFF)\: (t|T)he" * | xargs sed -r -i 's/(^(SEM|CON|AFF):\s)((t|T)he[ ]*)/\1/g'
```

Comment: This works well for the first part, but how can I proceed with the second part, i.e. where `the[ ]*` follows a comma? Also, why the `*` in front of the pipe?

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's/^ [SEM|AFF|CON] <+[:,]>  \s  <( [T|t] he \s+ //;'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
CON: the Unix and Linux question
SEM: eins, the zwei, drei
AUTH: , the
AFF: The holy seat
TTITLE: As we go, the Kuckuck comes too
```

Sample Output:

```
CON: Unix and Linux question
SEM: eins, the zwei, drei
AUTH: , the
AFF: holy seat
TTITLE: As we go, the Kuckuck comes too
```

Basically you can solve this problem easily if you understand/implement code using ***capture markers***. In Raku, the capture marker symbols are `<(`…`)>`. Not both capture markers need to be used.

What do capture markers do? Above in the recognition half of the `s///` substitution operator all elements get recognized:

`^ [SEM|AFF|CON] <+[:,]>  \s  <( [T|t] he \s+`

but because of the capture marker(s), only everything to the right of `<(` is retained as a "capture", i.e.:

`<( [T|t] he \s+`

Now that we have recognized a larger sequence, and retained a subsequence in a "capture", we replace that "capture" with nothing, obtaining the desired result. Note: the final regex atom in the code above is `\s+`, not `\s*`. This prevents `The` being deleted from the title, e.g. "Theory of Relativity".

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Capture_markers:_%3C(_)%3E
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org